# Prove that either $F\subseteq \operatorname{ker} f$ or else $R^\prime$ contains a subring isomorphic to $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

> Let $f$ be a homomorphism from the ring $R$ to $R^\prime$ and suppose that $R$ has a subring $F$ which is a field. It is required to prove that either $F\subseteq \operatorname{ker} f$ or else $R^\prime$ contains a subring isomorphic to $F$.

My attempt:

Suppose $F \nsubseteq\operatorname{ker}f $. Then there exists $a\in F$ such that $f(a)$ is not the zero element of $R^\prime$. Thus $a$ is nonzero and therefore invertible; say the inverse is $a^{-1}$. Define $f_a:F\to R^\prime$ by $$f_a(x)=f(axa^{-1}).$$ Then $f_a$ is a homomorphism. Now $f_a(F)$ is a subring of $R^\prime$ which is isomorphic to $F$. Hence the result.

Is this argument correct? Thanks.

Comment: Your argument is correct, but recall that $F$ is commutative (it's a field!), hence $axa^{-1}=x$.  A much simpler argument is this: $f|_F : F \to R'$ is a ring homomorphism, hence it is injective because $F$ is a field. This gives an isomorphism from $F$ to $f(F)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're apparently dealing with rings not necessarily with identity. Your argument is correct, but can be simplified.

Note that $\ker f\cap F$ is an ideal of $F$, so either $\ker f\cap F=\{0\}$ or $\ker f\cap F=F$ (that is, $F\subseteq\ker f$).

In the case $\ker f\cap F=\{0\}$, the homomorphism theorems tell you that
$$
F\cong F/\{0\}=F/(F\cap\ker f)\cong (F+\ker f)/\ker f\cong f(F)
$$

Remark. This doesn't use the commutativity of $F$, so it also holds under the assumption that $F$ is a division ring.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(F)$ is a field, since $f(F)\subset R'$ the claim follow. If $f(F)$ is not a field, then $f(F)=\{0\}$ and thus $F\subset \ker f$. For $f(F)=\{0\}$ do as follow : suppose there is $x$ s.t. $f(x)\neq 0$. Let $y$ the inverse of $x$ in $F$. Then $$1=f(1)=f(xy)=f(x)f(y),$$
and thus $f(x)$ is invertible what contradict that $f(F)$ is not a field.